# aircrack-ng: Interface wlp2s0 down

Tags: aircrack-ng

Im trying to learn using aircrack-ng.
I ran the following commands in order

```
#ifconfig “interface” down

#iwconfig “interface” mode monitor

#ifconfig “interface” up
airodump-ng -i “interface”
```

when  I run airodump-ng -i “interface” I get the following output

```
ioctl(SIOCSIWMODE) failed: Device or resource busy

 CH 11 ][ Elapsed: 3 mins ][ 2020-06-02 22:58 ][ interface wlp2s0 down                                         

 BSSID              PWR  Beacons    #Data, #/s  CH  MB   ENC  CIPHER AUTH ESSID


 BSSID              STATION            PWR   Rate    Lost    Frames  Probe
```

it shows no traffic ..How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should execute `airmon-ng` with channel monitor support.

```
 airmon-ng start wlan0 9
```

This way you can start monitor mode on channel 9.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. My chipset was RTL8812AU.
You just need to do the following-

```
airmon-ng check kill
```

After that, make sure you are disconnected to the internet, because your wifi adapter is now monitoring networks.
Then run,

```
airmon-ng start yourinterface
```

Check if monitor mode is enabled by doing `iwconfig`
Now use airodump-ng.